# Terminal: Hashcat charset - no matches found

Tags: macos, zip, zsh, hashcat

I'm trying to run hashcat to crack a zip file using the brute force method and I want to specify the character set using the below code in Mac M1 terminal: (where hcat.txt contains the hash of the zip file)

```
hashcat -a 3 -m 17225 --force hcat.txt ?l?l?l?l?l?l
```

But I got the below error.

```
zsh: no matches found: ?l?l?l?l?l?l
```

Comment: I think you just need to put quotes around the charset i.e. `hashcat -a 3 -m 17225 --force hcat.txt '?l?l?l?l?l?l'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply enclose the pattern in single quotes, such as '?l?l?l?l?l'

This is because zsh is attempting to interpret '?' as a glob expansion parameter, which means any single character such as '.' in regex.